# django how to place variable in a raw string,such as for URL router

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to write a url that could be configured when needed,for example:

```
url(r'^api/v1/books/',include('article.urls'))
```

in **settings.py** i set a `APIVERSION = 'api/v1'`

i want to put `APIVERSION` into that url to make it configureable,how to do that,is there a best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpattern = patterns('',
    url(settings.APIVERSION, include(
            url(r'/books/',include('article.urls'),
    )
)
```

In settings.py:

```
APIVERSION = r'^api/v1'
```

You can also avoid the nested include using a variable.

Answer (score 2):

@Luca's answer is right but I would be careful with breaking your backwards compatibility with your versioned URLs.

We had a similar situation and we ended up doing a decorator function that checks the version of the API from the request path.

```
#supports can be optional and defaults to current version
@check_version(supports="v1")
def view_function(...:
```

And url will use regex parameters like this,

```
^/api/v(?P<version>\d+)/
```

Comment: yeah,it seems more flexible and safe.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just use string concatenation, like below:

```
import settings

url(settings.APIVERSION + r'/books', include('article.urls'))
```

But, in the case of multiple versions of an API, I'm guessing you would want them all posted at the same time, so users aren't forced to immediately upgrade when you post a new version?

In that case I would use includes to reference difference versions and keep all of them, instead of a variable specifying only one.  Something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'/api/v1/books', include('api.v1.articles.urls')),
   url(r'/api/v2/books', include('api.v2.articles.urls')),
   url(r'/api/v3/books', include('api.v3.articles.urls')),
   ..
)
```

Or, if you want to handle the mapping in your request handler code, you could pull out the value as a variable

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'/api/v(?P<api_version>\d+)/books', 'articles.books.handler')
)
```

That would give you a named variable in your handler function to reference.  It would look something like this:

```
def handler(request, api_version):
   ... do something here...
```